# Object serialization produces different results on different machines

Tags: c#, serialization, json.net, .net-5, system.text.json

I have been trying to solve this problem for about 2 days and I have no idea what I should do next. On both PC of this question used a 64-bit system (Windows 10 on first PC, Windows Server 2012 on second PC). Project built with .NET 5.

**The details:**
I have simple anonymous object, that's need to be serialized:

```csharp
object s = new
{
    repositories = new
    {
        path= new
        {
            basePath= new
            {
                urlName = "https://example.com"
            }
        }
    },
    variables = new
    {
        alpha = new { value = "wagh89boa" },
        gamma = new { value = "f6q234v0go" },
    }
};
```

I am using `Newtonsoft.Json` for object serialization. On the first PC i get the expected result which is correct:

```csharp
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(s);
//{"repositories":{"path":{"basePath":{"urlName":"https://example.com"}}},"variables":{"alpha":{"value":"wagh89boa"},"gamma":{"value":"f6q234v0go"}}}
```

But when i run the same assembly on second PC (strictly speaking my app is running as Windows-service), I get wrong JSON string (2 braces after `"https://example.com"` insted of 3):

```csharp
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(s);
//{"repositories":{"path":{"basePath":{"urlName":"https://example.com"}},"variables":{"alpha":{"value":"wagh89boa"},"gamma":{"value":"f6q234v0go"}}}
```

What i tried to do:

- using `System.Text.Json` for serialization;
- create a separate model-class for each entity;
- create heir of `JsonConverter` with manually JSON creation;

None of these helped me solve the problem.
I would like to highlight the third point: I logged each step of the `JsonConverter.WriteJson()` (because I can't deploy the development environment on the second PC) method and found some strangeness: at the moment when I "closed the braces" after the `"https://example.com"`, the first two braces closed as expected, but the third never set on the 2-nd PC (on the 1-st PC converter works as expected). Here is the code of my converter (without logging):

```csharp
public class MyConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public override object? ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object? existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object? value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (value == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        //writer.AutoCompleteOnClose = false; //when using writer.WriteRaw("}");
        var properties = value.GetType().GetProperties();

        writer.WriteStartObject();

        foreach ( var property in properties ) 
        {
            writer.WritePropertyName(property.Name);
            if (property.PropertyType == typeof(string))
            {
                writer.WriteValue(property.GetValue(value));
            }
            else
            {
                serializer.Serialize(writer, property.GetValue(value));
            }
        }
        //none of this methods doesn't insert third brace after "https://example.com" on second PC and I absolutely don't understand why....
        writer.WriteEndObject();
        //writer.WriteEnd();
        //writer.WriteRaw("}");
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Best guess is that you are not calling `Dispose()` on the stream that is being opened so the data written at the end is not flushed to disk. But without seeing the object you are trying to serialize or the code that is calling `MyConverter` I can't be more helpful than that.

Comment: @NightOwl888 take a look at the begin of this question please. `object s` is the object, that i'm trying to serialize.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that. But like I said, you are probably not calling `Dispose()` after writing the stream. Any bytes that are left in the stream won't be flushed into the file if you don't call it.

Comment: What happens if you remove `MyConverter` and use Json.NET's built in tracing/logging functionality as described in [the docs](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializationTracing.htm)?  I'm thinking maybe your converter has a bug somewhere, so it might make sense to test without it.

Comment: @NightOwl888 @dbc Let me be clear: I came to use the `MyConverter` already AFTER I discovered the discrepancy between the behavior of two PCs. Incorrect json is generated on the second PC even when using the built-in Json.NET functionality, without using `MyConverter`

Comment: @NightOwl888 Can you clarify which stream you are talking about? I don't see any place in my scenario where i could use `Dispose()` (or am i missing something?...).   
Anyway, even if I will use `Dispose()`, it's not clear why serializing an object on one PC has a different result than serializing it on another PC

Comment: @Hominis_06 - Ah OK.  I might still recommend that you enable Json.NET tracing and compare the logs from the machine that works with the logs from the machine that does the wrong thing.  Set [`ITraceWriter.LevelFilter = TraceLevel.Verbose`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_ITraceWriter_LevelFilter.htm) to get as much trace info as possible.

Comment: Also, the fact that System.Text.Json produces the same result as Json.NET suggests that the object `s` is actually of a different type on the misbehaving computer.  Any chance of that you are running with an out-of-date DLL there, and the object isn't what you think it is?

Comment: @dbc Thanks for the answer, I'll try to use `ITraceWriter` asap.  S-object on the misbehaving PC is the same object as on a "correct" PC - 100%. About out-of-date DLL - this behavior is observed on Newtonsoft.Json v13.0.2 (latest at this moment) and System.Text.Json v5.0.2 (latest for .NET 5)

Comment: @Hominis_06 - Regarding out of date DLLs, I was referring to DLLs of your own application, not of System.Text.Json or Json.NET.  They fact that the two JSON libraries produce the same result despite sharing no code whatsoever suggests the problem isn't with JSON serialization at all.

Comment: @dbc ouch.. no, that's not possible either, I used the clean + rebuild app in my project as soon as I discovered misbehaving to eliminate that option right away

Comment: @Hominis_06 have you tried it on third server?

Comment: Unfortunately .NET 5 is no longer supported. See [.NET and .NET Core Support Policy](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/platform/support/policy/dotnet-core) for more information.

Comment: @Hominis_06 - I am referring to the stream that is being used (or contained within) the JsonWriter. Streams are disposable objects, meaning they need to be used in a [using statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement) or try/catch block in order to dispose them properly. [JsonTextWriter accepts a TextWriter](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonTextWriter__ctor.htm) in the constructor and `TextWriter` should be disposed.

Comment: Of course, it would help if you would provide the code that creates the writer and calls `WriteJson()` so we can see that it is being disposed of properly. But from the behavior you describe 1) works on one machine but not another 2) open elements in the stream not being closed - not calling `Dispose()` could definitely explain that behavior.

Comment: @NightOwl888 shouldn't it be serializer which opens/closes the stream?

Comment: No, it is you who does it and passes the stream into the `JsonWriter`. The problem here is that you didn't post that bit and assumed the problem lies somewhere in the serializer code, which is probably working fine. But you likely aren't flushing the last part of the stream to the disk, so you are missing the end of what `JsonWriter` adds to the stream in the file (or other destination). Streams are buffered. You need to ensure the buffer is flushed to the disk before closing it. Calling `Dispose()` does that as well as closes resources (such as file handles).

Comment: @NightOwl888 first of all I can't post that bit cause I don't have it cause it is not my question, second of all we have `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(s)` posted as code used to serialize object, 3) the code handling the stream is in custom converter as far as I can see, so why do you assume that someone else is managing the streams directly (I maybe missing something here) 4) OP claims that this happens even if no custom serializer is used.

Comment: Again, `JsonWriter` by definition owns a stream. Your method accepts `JsonWriter` as a parameter. Whatever is creating that stream is also responsible for disposing it. But since you are not showing the bit that creates the stream, people looking at this question have no way of knowing if you are actually disposing the stream. All of the issues you describe can be explained by not correctly [using objects that implement IDisposable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/using-objects): without seeing the code that does it you have asked an unanswerable question.

Comment: @NightOwl888 I apologize if my example misled you. `MyConverter` that given in the question is used exactly [as described in the documentation for custom converters](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm). You're right that the `JsonWriter` does have its own stream, but my code has nothing to do with it since the `JsonWriter`'s stream is managed by Newtonsoft.Json Serializer

Comment: My apologies. I didn't realize that you were implementing a feature on top of their base class that is called internally. But then, that example code and a link to the documentation should be in your question, since you haven't included enough code for people to run it. See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Please edit your question to include that and you will be much more likely to get an answer.